# Call a controller method (patch) when a table row is clicked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How do I call a specific method in my controller when a table row is clicked?

I have seen lots of solutions that use `window.location`, but in my case the method is not a `get` but a `patch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(
  $('tr').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url : 'YOUR_URL',
      data : JSON.stringify(YOUR_DATA),
      type : 'PATCH',
      contentType : 'application/json',
      processData: false,
      dataType: 'json'
    )};
  });
)
```

This sample requires jquery and send data in json.